# Load Many to Many Collections same time as object itself

Tags: java, hibernate

I have `ManyToMany` mapping, I mapped `Car` model, and `Monter` model, I get them to save to database and that works fine, however when I retrieve my car object I can't access my collections, because I get lazy load error.

This is my service Impl :

```
@Override
public List<FinishedCar> finishedCarList() {
    return finishedCarDao.findAll() ;
}
```

Now I read somewhere that I can use `fetchType.Eager`, but for some reason this does not work in my case, so I found `Hibernate.initialize()` method, but I don't know how (or better yet) where to use it ?

Should I use `hibernate.initialize()` method in my service layer ? or Dao ? and how would I load my collection without getting lazy load error. Also, does that mean that on every instance of object car I must use `hibernate.initialize()`

I use `car.getMonterMain()` to call my `getter` in car class.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="car_worker",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
public List<FinishedCar> getFinishedCar() {
    return finishedCar;
}


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="car_worker",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "worker_type = 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cascade` to store child object and `FetchType.LAZY` to get child object with parent entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "FOrd", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<FOrdItem> FOrdItems;
```

and in DAO you have to use  `.size()` method on child object:

```
fOrd.getFOrdItems().size();
```

`fOrd` is parent entity and `getFOrdItems()` to get child(FOrdItems).

when you use `.size()` child entity will load.

Comment: i updated my original question with mappings from my model.
Problem is if i add cascade type.all to many to many annotation i get following error :

 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.atlas.model.Monter;

if i dont use cascade then i can save that to database ,